# PowerShell output to textbox

Tags: c#, powershell

I wanna get all the details from the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-NetConnectionProfile` but it doesn't show it in the textbox and I don't really know why.

[image: Console Screenshot]

I tried other "get" cmdlets like `Get-NetAdapter`, which worked perfectly.
I could see everything in the textbox.

```cs
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
var proc = Process.Start(psi);

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Get-NetConnectionProfile");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

TxtIp.Text = s;
```

Comment: This isn't a great way to use PowerShell from C#.  You should use the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0) class instead of trying to run your commands in a separate process.

Comment: Does Get-NetConnectionProfile work in PowerShell? What output do you expect? You may need to pipe the results

Comment: By "all details", I assume you mean the default output seen when you run Get-NetConnectionProfile. See my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "all details", I assume you mean the default output seen when you run `Get-NetConnectionProfile`:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-NetConnectionProfile

Name             : E12345
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex   : 15
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : Internet
```

Program 1 is a pure `PowerShell` solution using `WinForms`

I tried to execute `Get-NetConnectionProfile` from c# (see [Creating an InitialSessionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/creating-an-initialsessionstate) but got a `Provider load failure' and could not solve the issue (This is the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0) class solution mentioned by [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog)).

Note: I have had success with executing `PowerShell` cmdlets from a C# program (see [How do I login to a XEN session from a C# program using a secure string password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520233/how-do-i-login-to-a-xen-session-from-a-c-sharp-program-using-a-secure-string-pas/53526831#53526831) so I know its possible

**Program 1**

```
#region functions

Function ButtonGo_Click
{
    $output = Get-NetConnectionProfile
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = ("Name="+$output.Name.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine)
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = $textBoxDisplay.Text + ("InterfaceAlias="+$output.InterfaceAlias.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine)
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = $textBoxDisplay.Text + ("InterfaceIndex="+$output.InterfaceIndex.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine)
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = $textBoxDisplay.Text + ("NetworkCategory="+$output.NetworkCategory.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine)
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = $textBoxDisplay.Text + ("IPv4Connectivity="+$output.IPv4Connectivity.ToString() + [Environment]::NewLine)
    $textBoxDisplay.Text = $textBoxDisplay.Text + "IPv6Connectivity="+$output.IPv6Connectivity.ToString()
}

#endregion

#region designer

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$buttonGo = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$buttonGo.Location = '10, 10'
$buttonGo.Name = "buttonGo"
$buttonGo.Size = '75, 25'
$buttonGo.TabIndex = 0
$buttonGo.Text = "&Go"
$buttonGo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$buttonGo.Add_Click({ButtonGo_Click})

$textBoxDisplay = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$textBoxDisplay.Location = '12, 50'
$textBoxDisplay.Multiline = $true
$textBoxDisplay.Name = "textBoxDisplay"
$textBoxDisplay.Size = '470, 150'
$textBoxDisplay.TabIndex = 1

$mainForm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$mainForm.Size = '500, 250'
$mainForm.Controls.Add($buttonGo)
$mainForm.Controls.Add($textBoxDisplay)
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$mainForm.Name = "mainForm"
$mainForm.Text = "Show Get-NetConnectionProfile Output"

#endregion designer

cls
$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

**Output**

[image]